# Name of node in launch file should be same as the name in script? #ROS #rospy

Tags: ros, rospy

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

rospy.init_node('ardrone_action_server')
ArdroneAS()
rospy.spin()
```

I have initialized the node with rospy but should I name the node identical with the name in python script?

Below is the launch file:

```
<launch>
<node name="ardrone_as" pkg="ardrone_as" type="action_server.py" output="screen">

</node>
```

Only the node name is showing in the launch file when running. Why is that?

Comment: Probably english is not your first language. There is no problem in that. Try to spend a little bit of time when writing your question. :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the common behavior of setting the node name in a launch files. It remaps (overrides) the node name which is defined in code. You can find the specification of this at [chapter 5 of the ROS node documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/Nodes):

> __name is a special reserved keyword for "the name of the node." It lets you remap the node name without having to know its
>   actual name. It can only be used if the program that is being launched
>   contains one node.